# Converting and sending date as a URL QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to trigger an URL to the browser control in my application. The URL contains a querystring of format DateTime.

Example : http://localhost:31401/WebSite4/PopUp.aspx?DateTime=12%2F10%2F2011+10%3A22%3A11

My problem here is that i have to remove the "/" (Slash) & ":"(Colon) in the date time and add "%2F" & "%3A" in place of these.

Example : 12/10/2011 10:22:11 should be converted to 12%2F10%2F2011+10%3A22%3A11

Is there any built-in method or way to do it? or Shall i have to replace them thorugh manual code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
 System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("12/10/2011 10:22:11")
```

Gives

```
 12%2f10%2f2011+10%3a22%3a11
```

You will need to add reference to **System.Web**.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Try UrlEncode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: Decoding is not at all a problem. I've to encode it while sending it from my Standalone app to browser control.

Comment: You asked for a way to convert from "normal string" to "url string", which is what UrlEncode does. If you're looking for something else, I'm not sure I understand what. :)

Comment: Example : 12/10/2011 10:22:11 should be converted to 12%2F10%2F2011+10%3A22%3A11

Comment: Indeed. Amar Palsapure, whose answer you've accepted, has suggested the same thing as me, so I think it all will work out nicely in the end. Good luck!

Comment: You just have to make sure you convert the DateTime to a string